# Extracting text between quotes that has escaped quotes

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
text()=["He said\"Hello\""]/something
```

I want to write a regular expression to extract the following string from the above string:

```
He said \"Hello\"
```

How do I go about doing this?
I am writing the code in Java.

Comment: Yes. That's my actual string.

Comment: I'm taking input from the user and the user will enter the string exactly as I have typed above, in the command line. I store it in a variable. So the variable will have the string exactly as shown above character for character.

Comment: Wouldn't the result be `He said\"Hello\"`

Comment: Yes that would be the result. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern

```
"((?:\\"|[^"])*)"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/236)
resutls = `He said\"Hello\"`
then simply replace `\"` with `"`

Comment: How would I modify this for a non-greedy match? If my string is 

/foo/bar[text()="He said \"Hello\""][text()="hello"] 
then i want it to stop at the first non escaped quote. So the output should be He said \"Hello\" for  this example.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you double escape in the regex? Such as \ which should match all single \?

In other words you are escaping the escape character so that you can match it.

Comment: darn, my double escape got escaped on the text :O, what I mean is two back slashes next to each other such as "\\" however this might be escaped once I submit this comment.